# Unexpected double quotes while appending file items to subprocess.run

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, subprocess

I am trying to read from a file which has contents like this:

```
@\5\5\5
...
@\5\5\10
```

This file content is then fed into subprocess module of python like this:

```
    for lines in file.readlines():
      print(lines)
      cmd = ls
      p = subprocess.run([cmd, lines])
```

The output turns into something like this:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['ls', "'@5\\5\\5'\n"], returncode=1)
```

I don't understand why the contents of the file is appended with a double quote and another backward slash is getting appended.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here isn't Python or the `subprocess` module. The problem the use of `subprocess` to invoke shell commands, and then trying to parse the results. In this case, it looks like the command is `ls`, and the plan appears to be to read some filesystem paths from a text file (each path on a separate line), and list the files at that location on the filesystem.

Using `subprocess` to invoke `ls` is really, *really*, ***really*** not the way to accomplish that in Python. This is basically an attempt to use Python like a shell script (this use of `ls` would still be problematic, but that's a different discussion).

If a shell script is the right tool for the job, then write a shell script. If you want to use Python, then use one of the API's that it provides for interacting with the OS and the filesystem. There is no need to bring in external programs to achieve this.

```
import os

with open("list_of_paths.txt", "r") as fin:
    for line in fin.readlines():
        w = os.listdir(line.strip())
        print(w)
```

Note the use of `.strip()`, this is a string method that will remove invisible characters like spaces and newlines from the ends of the input.

The `listdir` method provided by the `os` module will return a list of the files in a directory. Other options are `os.scandir`, `os.walk`, and the `pathlib` module.

But please do not use `subprocess`. 95% of the time, when someone thinks "should I use Python's `subprocess` module for this?" the ansewr is "NO".

Comment: Hi there, you are absolutely right that I shouldn't be using python's subprocess module in this way. I gave example of 'ls' command but I was not not using ls for the actual work that I needed to be done. I was also using subprocess module because I wanted to handle exceptions from the command that I want to be executed.

Comment: @ShivamPrakhar The `\n` is called an *escape sequence* which is just a sequence of characters that represent something different than the literal characters of the sequence, usually to represent a special character that can't be entered into a string directly. in this case it is the new line character on the end of each line. you can remove those using `strip` as mentioned in my answer.  Regarding the extra single quotes that appear in the sample output, those will not occur using the sample input and code snippet, so there is no way to tell where those are coming from with the info provided.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I solved this problem long back though by changing the entire approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `\` with a relevant character or digit becomes something else other than the string. For example, `\n` is not just \ and n but it means next line. If you really want a `\n`, then you would add another backslash to it (`\\n`). Likewise `\5` means something else. here is what I found when i ran `\5`:
[image]

and hence the `\\` being added, if I am not wrong

Comment: I want the program to take the content of the file as is, not expecting anything to be added other than what is in the file.

Comment: Nothing's been added. You are just seeing Python's representation of a string containing the shell's representation of a string passed to `ls`.

Comment: any suggestion on how to escape it and using the string as is?

Comment: At this point in time, I am not clear if this is the right and optimal thing to do, but you may take the result and use `regex` on it - add an `r` infront to make it a raw string and replace one of the `\` from the doubles with `''`. Or instead of regex use string substitute.
Although as @chepner pointed out, it's just a representation of Python. You wanted it to escape, but it indeed in itself is an escape character. Anyway, if you still wanted it, you may try as I said, but I am not sure if it pans out well. Just try and check.